# Hide plugins and theme from public

Tags: plugins, security, sitemap, robots.txt

I like to hide all or some of my plugins and themes and CMS from public such that the users cannot detect which plugins/themes/CMS I used to build my website.

Please let me know if it is possible to do that in WordPress.

Thanks.

Comment: Generally this measure is not worth the considerably extensive effort required to achieve such a result. Even the [U.S. Whitehouse](https://www.whitehouse.gov/) doesn't bother concealing that it uses WordPress nor it's theme or plugins. Why do you want/what are you hoping to achieve with this sort of obscurity?

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that concealing WordPress and it's extensions is not a function facilitated by WordPress core itself - this sort of thing generally falls into the realms of third-party functionality and server configuration, which may make the question [off-topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for our stack.